# How do you check if value exists within Firebase live database using Firebase Functions?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to setup a live database through firebase and test if a random value exists within it using Firebase Functions. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

I have tried the code below but ended up getting 'unhandled error event'.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

exports.Exists = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  console.log("Hello from Firebase!");
   var result           = '';
   var characters       = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNPRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijkmnpqrstuvwxyz23456789';
   var charactersLength = characters.length;
   for ( var i = 0; i < 4; i++ ) {
      result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength));
   }
   return admin.database().ref().once(result).then(snap => {
  if (snap.exists()) {
    response.send("exists");
  }else{
      response.send(result);
  }
});
```

- FireBase Name

  - Value
  - Value
  - Value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.test = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {

    return ExistTest();


    function RandCharGen(length){

        var result = '';
        var characters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNPRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijkmnpqrstuvwxyz23456789';
        var charactersLength = characters.length;

        for ( var i = 0; i < length; i++ ) {
            result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength));
        }

        return result;
    }

    function ExistTest(){
        var result = RandCharGen(4);
    admin.database().ref(result).once('value', (snapshot) => {
          if (snapshot.exists()) {
              ExistTest();
        }
        else{
                response.send(result);
            return result;
        }
        });
    }
});
```

For anyone who wants the correct answer or knows a cleaner way of doing so.

Answer (score 1):

You got your database call jumble around, it should be

```
admin.database().ref(result).once('value').then(snap => ...)
```

- `result` is the key you are looking for
- `value` is the event you are listening for "once", you can also continue to listen for value changes via `ref().on('value', callback)`

Here is the relevant section from the docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#read_data_once